# Route53 over VPN IPSec and Openvpn

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

I have got vpn connection: (`aws vpn ipsec bgp)<->linux strongswan to vpc subnet:10.215.0.0/16.`
In linux machine I have got Openvpn as server whitch push route to 10.215.0.0/16. Now my Desktop PC over Opnevpn can connect to aws vpc 10.215.0.0/16.e.g:

```
(aws vpn ipsec bgp)<->linux strongswan to vpc subnet:10.215.0.0/16, openvpn<->Desktop PC with access to 10.215.0.0/16 vpc.
```

I can get access to e.g. `ssh admin@10.215.2.23`
Now I want to set route53(private mode) to resolve 10.215.2.23 as server1.hosting.xz, so I created a route53 and in 10.215.2.23 server it is auto working.

> And now i question.

What should I do to push route53 over openvpn? I want to resolve hostnames on my Desktop PC.

```
push "dhcp-option WHAT_IP?"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN mydomain.xx"
```